# What nested filter format Loopback application should support?

Tags: strongloop, connector, loopback4

In the LoopBack application we need to develop a generic logic to parse the where filter provided to the application **to convert that where filter into endpoint supported query format.**

**We are checking on what complex/nested filter formats loopback supports.**

While checking for it we found the [Where Builder](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Where-filter.html#wherebuilder) class available  in LoopBack 4. We checked it to know how it prepares where filter for complex/nested filters. However, we couldn't conclude using it. Please find below our understanding and queries on few clauses we tried:

**Points to consider when going through our analysis mentioned below:**

1. We explored Where Builder to know loopback standards (considering Where builder must be creating complex/nested filter as per LoopBack standards, which loopback app should supports)
2. In each analysis point below in last point which read ***From this filter query can be formed:*** we have added representation of condition and not formed the query using properties key and value mentioned in filter and also updated filter generated by where builder with `and1, and2, or1, or2` etc to make query readable.
3. In our connector application we get where filter (we test our app using Postman as well), we get whatever filter user provides, but **we need to know what complex/nested filter we should support as a standard LoopBack application.**

**Analysis of different clause we tried using Where Builder:**

1. For clause below:

```
const where = whereBuilderObj
    .eq('a', 1)
    .and({x: 'x'}, {y: {gt: 1}})
    .and({b: 'b'}, {c: {lt: 1}})
    .or({d: 'd'}, {e: {neq: 1}})
    .build();
```

It created where filter as below:

```
{
    "and": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "and1": [
                {
                    "x": "x"
                },
                {
                    "y": {
                        "gt": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "and2": [
                {
                    "b": "b"
                },
                {
                    "c": {
                        "lt": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "or": [
        {
            "d": "d"
        },
        {
            "e": {
                "neq": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

From this filter query can be formed:  `a === 1 && and1_Condition && and2_Condition || or_Condition`

2. For clause below:

```
const where = whereBuilderObj
  .eq('a', 1)
  .and({x: 'x'}, {y: {gt: 1}})
  .or({l: 'l1'}, {m: {neq: 2}})
  .and({b: 'b'}, {c: {lt: 1}})
  .or({d: 'd'}, {e: {neq: 1}})
  .build();
```

It created where filter as below:

```
{
    "and": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "and1": [
                {
                    "x": "x"
                },
                {
                    "y": {
                        "gt": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "or1": [
                {
                    "l": "l1"
                },
                {
                    "m": {
                        "neq": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "and2": [
                {
                    "b": "b"
                },
                {
                    "c": {
                        "lt": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "or": [
        {
            "d": "d"
        },
        {
            "e": {
                "neq": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

From this filter query can be formed: `a === 1 && and1_Condition && or1_Condition && and2_Condition || or_Condition`

3. For clause below:

```
const where = whereBuilderObj
  .eq('a', 1)
  .and({x: 'x'}, {y: {gt: 1}})
  .or({l: 'l1'}, {m: {neq: 2}})
  .and({b: 'b'}, {c: {lt: 1}})
  .or({d: 'd'}, {e: {neq: 1}})
  .neq('az', 1)
  .build();
```

It created where filter as below:

```
{
    "and": [
        {
            "a": 1,
            "and1": [
                {
                    "x": "x"
                },
                {
                    "y": {
                        "gt": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "or1": [
                {
                    "l": "l1"
                },
                {
                    "m": {
                        "neq": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "and2": [
                {
                    "b": "b"
                },
                {
                    "c": {
                        "lt": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "or": [
        {
            "d": "d"
        },
        {
            "e": {
                "neq": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "az": {
        "neq": 1
    }
}
```

What is the correct query should get formed using this above filter? We tried to form like - `a ===1 && and1_Condition && or1_Condition && and2_Condition || or_Condition ?? az !=1` but didn't get which filter clause/operator we should use for **az** property (hence added **??**). This query is from analysis we did by using WhereBuilder, but **at the end we need to know what complex/nested filter we should support as a standard LoopBack application.**

Could someone please help us on our queries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Yash, I am not sure what you mean when you say ***we need to know what complex/nested filter we should support as a standard LoopBack application***. I imagine that would be an engineering decision made by your team. However, you can see what the queries generated by Loopback by adding the debug string in your environment e.g.

```
$ DEBUG=loopback:datasource,loopback:connector:* yarn start
```

This will print the debug strings including the SQL query that was executed.